# How to select three columns from two tables and group by only two columns in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, multiple-columns

I have an SQL Query that's working, but I need to add one more column. This column is on a different table and I can't figure out how to bring it all together.

Here's the code that works... it's selecting all active users who share a first and last name with another user (we're looking for duplicates)

```
SELECT UserTable.LastName, 
       UserTable.FirstName 
FROM UserTable
INNER JOIN InfoTable 
  ON InfoTable.ID=UserTable.ID
WHERE InfoTable.Number > 2500 and Infotable.Inactive = 0
GROUP BY FirstName, 
         LastName
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

What I need to do is modify this code so that I can display the column NUMBER which is located on InfoTable, however I do not want to include NUMBER in the GROUP BY, because NUMBER is always going to be unique, so it would return no results.

Comment: What do you mean with "because NUMBER is always going to be unique"

Comment: The column's name is NUMBER.  Each user has a unique value in that column, so it cannot be included in the GROUP BY.

Comment: If _NUMBER_ always is unique you can add it to your `GROUP BY`statement without any negative result. Of course you could use `MIN(NUMBER)` or `MAX(NUMBER)` in your `SELECT` statement as well

Comment: @schlonzo - When I added _NUMBER_ I received no results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your RDBMS supports windows functions (aka OLAP functions), you can simply do :

```
SELECT x.*
FROM (
    SELECT 
        u.LastName, 
        u.FirstName,
        i.Number,
        COUNT(u.ID) OVER (PARTITION BY u.LastName, u.FirstName) cnt
    FROM 
        UserTable u
        INNER JOIN InfoTable i 
            ON  u.ID = I.ID
            AND i.Number > 2500 
            AND i.Inactive = 0
) x WHERE x.cnt > 1
ORDER BY 1, 2, 3
```

The inner query uses `COUNT ... OVER` to add to each record the count of users that have the same first and last name , and the outer query filters in homonyms.

Answer (score 0):

You can't `SELECT` columns that are not in the `GROUP BY`. A `GROUP BY` clause tells the engine to create groups out of the specified columns. Once the rows are grouped, you can only `SELECT` columns in the `GROUP BY` clause, or aggregates of the non-grouped columns.

Something like this should work. First the subquery gets the duplicate `FirstName`/`LastName` pairs, then the main query `JOIN`s back to the original tables to show you the output you want.

```
SELECT I.Number, U.LastName, U.FirstName
FROM InfoTable I
JOIN UserTable U
ON I.ID = U.ID
JOIN
(
    SELECT U.LastName, U.FirstName
    FROM UserTable U
    JOIN InfoTable I
    ON U.ID = I.ID
    WHERE I.Number > 2500 AND I.Inactive = 0
    GROUP BY U.LastName, U.FirstName
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) T
ON U.FirstName = T.FirstName AND U.LastName = T.LastName
ORDER BY I.Number, U.LastName, U.FirstName
```